# Why am i getting this Fatal Error Message

Tags: php, woocommerce, runtime-error

I wrote my own shortcode for woocommerce.

The code works fine on content-single-product.php.
Any other page though, and my site breaks. Why?

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_gallery_image_ids() on null in /mysite/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-thumbnails.php on line 27
```

This is the function i wrote:

```
/* My custom shortcode code*/
function get_woocommerce_gallery_image_thumbnails ( $atts ) {

     // Buffer our contents
     ob_start();

     /* Line to get the gallery thumbnails */
wc_get_template( 'single-product/product-thumbnails.php');

     // Return buffered contents
     return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'wc_get_thumbs', 'get_woocommerce_gallery_image_thumbnails' );
```

Comment: There is a missing object which holds the `get_gallery_image_ids()` method.

Comment: lets say `$foo->get_gallery_image_ids()` is the function then `$foo` is null

Comment: im still not understanding. Why would the code work perfectly fine on my product page, but not fine everywhere else? What exactly do i write and where would i write it to overcome the error?

Answer (score 0):

According to the given information, every page asks for `*something*->get_gallery_image_ids()`, but `*something*` only exists on your product page. Looking at the available data, this `*something*` is presumably created in the `product-thumbnails` template.

With the information from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54816946/9254201), we can see that the `*something*` is actually a `global $product`, which is required for the `product-thumbnails`.

The best solution, I suppose, is to remove `product-thumbnails` from every page that is not a product page.

As an alternative, you could add a safeguard in your shortcode definition:

```
function get_woocommerce_gallery_image_thumbnails ( $atts ) {
     global $product;
     if (!isset($product)) {
         return;
     }

     // Buffer our contents
     ob_start();

     /* Line to get the gallery thumbnails */
     wc_get_template( 'single-product/product-thumbnails.php');

     // Return buffered contents
     return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Ooops you are right, I didn't notice `$product` was already global in `product-thumbnails.php`.  In that case my answer won't work, I deleted it. Good catch!

Comment: Heh, I don't think it was necessary to delete it.. I wouldn't have guessed that the something I'd been describing was a `global $product` if it hadn't been for your answer.

Comment: I mean...i don't know if that will work either. i first tried it on a page that had nothing related to products, and it still broke. So i don't know what's the fix here

Comment: Well, that's exactly the point: because you want to get the product thumbnails on a page that has nothing to do with products, wordpress breaks down. As for the fix, refer to the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: Ah nvm, I just thought of an alternative. I'll update the answer.

Comment: The best thing is still to not put the tag for the thumbnails of a single product on every page, even those that have "nothing related to products".